# Deaccumulate values in sas

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset that looks like the following:

```
  Year  Qtr Variable
2009    1   10
2009    2   15
2009    3   20
2009    4   25
2010    1   5
2010    2   7
2010    3   9
2010    4   12
2011    1   14
2011    2   17
2011    3   21
2011    4   26
```

The variable gets accumulated over quarters. I want to replace that variable with the actual increase during the quarter i.e., I want the table to look like:

```
Year    Qtr Variable
2009    1   10
2009    2   5
2009    3   5
2009    4   5
2010    1   5
2010    2   2
2010    3   2
2010    4   3
2011    1   14
2011    2   3
2011    3   4
2011    4   5
```

If it is the first quarter leave the value unchanged, otherwise subtract the previous value.
Is there any command to do this in SAS?

Also, not sure if it helps, but this is what I am trying to do:

```
data ppe;
set ppeqrt;
by gvkey;
where (sppey>=0 or sppey=.) and sppey not in (1,2,3,7,.c,.i,.a,.s);
year=year(datadate);
qtr=qtr(datadate);
keep ppentq sppey year qtr;

**** Here I am missing the differences of sppey by year and quarter whithin each gvkey (I did not include this variable above not to burden this) ******    


proc means data=ppe noprint;
var ppentq sppey; 
class year qtr;
types year*qtr;
output out=ppesums mean= sum=/autoname;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to `lag` is the `dif` function which is precisely what you need I think.  It performs both the lag and the subtraction at the same time.  I show `ifn` here which allows `dif` (or `lag`) to work as desired in this setup (but you could just as easily do it in a separate variable like Andrew does).

```
data have;
input Year  Qtr Variable;
datalines;
2009    1   10
2009    2   15
2009    3   20
2009    4   25
2010    1   5
2010    2   7
2010    3   9
2010    4   12
2011    1   14
2011    2   17
2011    3   21
2011    4   26
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by year qtr;
  variable = ifn(first.year,variable,dif(variable));
run;
```

If you have another grouping variable the grouping variable goes before `year` in the `by` statement.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up using this solution that seems neater. Works like charm!

Comment: Props to the dif statement, didn't even pop in to my head. Also love the use of ifn()!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data are sorted by Year (if not just proc sort them), then the lag function works well:

```
data want;
   set have;
   by year;

   lag_var = lag(variable);

   if first.year ^= 1 then Variable = Variable - lag_var;

   drop lag_var;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just two clarifications:
1) it should not be first year but first quarter ... for each first quarter I want to keep the value ... Or does first.year take the first time a year shows up (and that's why sorting is important?)

2) If I have multiple groups (the variable gvkey), each one with a data similar to the one above (year, quarter, variable) can I account for that as well?

Comment: first.year is a binary variable that is 1 if that is the first time the year appears. For this example you want to subtract the previous value from your second value except on the first one, hence the first.year^=1.

As for the gvkey variable, it is hard to tell without seeing what the variable looks like (you could update your question) but it could still work, or may be a small change with the by and first. statements.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am on my phone so I can't update the question right now but will do as soon as I get back to the office. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Just a note about the DIF function:
As shown, using the IFN function, it works as intended. But only because the IFN function always calculates both output values before choosing one.
In other words, this works:

```
variable = ifn(first.year,variable,dif(variable));
```

but this does not:

```
if not first.year then variable=dif(variable);
```

because the DIF function should be called every time to work as intended here, as the DIF and LAG functions work by storing value(s) from previous calls in an internal stack.